# Crear un Facade Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

soy nuevo usando laravel y lo que quiero hacer incorporar a mi proyecto una clase propia que tengo desarrollada.

Eh intentado seguir los pasos de este [link](https://styde.net/facades-automaticos-en-laravel-5-4/) pero no me sale, lo que eh realizado hasta el momento es lo siguiente:

**1.)** Crear el Alias config\app.php:

```
'Alert' => 'Facades\App\Alert',
```

**2.)** Crear el Archivo que almacena la clase en la carpeta App (app\ **Alert.php**)
Este es el contenido de la clase:

```
<?php  

    namespace App;

    class Alert 
    {
        public function message($message, $type)
        {
            return $message;
        }

        public function render()
        {
            return 'render';
        }
    }

?>
```

**3.)** Cree el Controlador AlertController de la siguiente manera:

```
 php artisan make:controller AlertController
```

Agrege al controlador el facade:

```
<?php
    namespace Sistem_Administrador\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Facades\App\Alert; //<-Facade agregado

    class AlertController extends Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            return Alert::message('Mensaje1','Typo1');
        }
    }
```

**4.)** Cree la Ruta en el archivo routes\web.php

```
Route::get('/Alert','AlertController@index');
```

No se si me falta algún paso pero hasta donde vi en la pagina que les mencione antes, eso seria todo, la versión de laravel que tengo es la 5.4

El error que me retorna dice que Class App\Alert does not exist , como se ve en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

ya pude solucionar mi problema y dejare la solución en caso de que a alguien se le presente la misma situación:

Los pasos que realice estaban correcto, lo único que me toco hacer fue busar "autoload" dentro del archivo **composer.json** y agregar mi clase, en caso de que no exista, hay que agregarlo

```
"autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                "database",
                "app/Alert.php" <- La linea que agregue
            ]
}
```

Después de agregarla en la consola solo debo ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

Y listo, ya ejecuta sin problemas, Gracias de todos modos a quienes se molestaron en reviasr :) .